# Java inheritance appending a function instead of overwriting it

Tags: java, oop

```
public class Cls1{
    public foo(){
        doX();
    }
}

public class Cls2{
    public foo(){
        doY();
    }
}

Cls2 cls = new Cls2();
cls.foo();
```

Is there a way to do inheritance in java that java runs both doX and doY when the user calls the function with foo?

Comment: That would completely violate basic OOP principles

Comment: `Cls1` and `Cls2` don't inherit from each other and thus have no real relationship.  What are you asking exactly?

Comment: normally in the extended function you would call base.foo().  I do not know if that is correct java syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you have to do it explicitly:

```
public class Cls1{
    public foo{
        doX();
    }
}

public class Cls2 extends Cls1 {
    public foo{
        super.foo();
        doY();
    }
}
```

Note: I assume you meant for Cls2 to extend Cls1, otherwise your question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Cls1 {
    public foo{
        doX();
    }
}

public class Cls2 extends Cls1 {
    public foo{
        super.foo();
        doY();
    }
}

Cls2 cls = new Cls2();
cls.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private class Cls2 extends Cls1 {      
    public void foo {
        doY();
        super.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I assume you mean:

```
public class Cls2 extends Cls1{
```

and yes, there is:

```
public (something?) foo(){
    super.foo();
    doY();
}
```

The super keyword allows access to the super-class's methods. If it's simply called on its own:

```
super(...);
```

then it calls the super-class's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Cls1` and `Cls2` inherit from each other in some way, you can use the keyword `super` to call the superclass's implementation of a method if you want to, for instance, in the derived class perform both functions.

Answer (score 0):

If doX() and doY() were statically imported (which, as they were not defined in Cls1 or in Cls2 is the only way I can think of for this program to compile), then you can make a new class with a method foo that calls doX and doY without using inheritance.  Those methods named foo would have nothing to do with each other, however.